# converted angular 2 web app to mobile app

Tags: cordova, angular, mobile

I have a simple angular2 application and I want to create a mobile app for this app using cordova. How can I covert this web app to mobile app without using ionic and nativeScrypte?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn Angular JS 2 app into mobile app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649500/turn-angular-js-2-app-into-mobile-app)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your transpiled source is, copy it to cordova's www folder.

I will explain this with respect to Angular CLI.

I created two projects, one Angular CLI & one Cordova.

In Angular CLI's config json, i kept production o/p Dir -->Cordova's www directory.

Then whenever i do ng build --prod, it automatically keeps the transpiled src in cordova's www & Then able to make a cordova build.

To simplify the process i wrote 1 cordova hook, which does ng prod build before cordova build/run .

```
const fs = require('fs');
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;



module.exports = function(context) {
    const basePath = context.opts.projectRoot;
    const baseWWW = basePath + '/www';

process.chdir('../bmi-surgical-app');
console.log(`New directory: ${process.cwd()}`);

    execSync("ng build --prod --base-href .",{stdio:[0,1,2]});

    var files = fs.readdirSync(baseWWW);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (files[i].endsWith('.gz')) {
        fs.unlinkSync(baseWWW + '/' + files[i]);
      }
    }
    fs.writeFileSync(baseWWW + '/.gitignore', `# Ignore everything in this directory

*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
`);


};
```

Comment: it works but the mobile app is always in loading it don't  display anyt hings ,

Comment: it works but the mobile app is always in loading it don't  display any things , it not displays data that  my appcompanents contains

Comment: Open browser console and check error  console which error it displays...i guess your error is not proper base href