# Does angular4 empower you to generate native mobile code/binary without any external framework which angular2 was not capable of?

Tags: angular

What does 'Develop Across All Platforms' in angular4 mean?

https://angular.io says

> Learn one way to build applications with Angular and reuse your code
>   and abilities to build apps for any deployment target. For web, mobile
>   web, native mobile and native desktop.

Does it mean you can generate native android/ios/desktop apps from angular web client project(killing hybrid frameworks like ionic)? Or does it mean you can embed the entire web client inside a android/ios app such that its indistinguishable ? I don't see any reference to generating native apps in documentation though.

Comment: https://angular.io/features.html.  The angular code should be the same no matter what target;  examples of targets include Ionic Framework, NativeSript, React Native, JavaScript, Windows/Mac Desktop OS, etc.

Comment: `Build native mobile apps with strategies from Ionic Framework, NativeScript, and React Native.` what does `strategies from` imply, I don't see anything in docs how to implement strategies from those ?

Comment: ok got it, it says  `Many Angular libraries are modules (such as FormsModule, HttpModule, and RouterModule). Many third-party libraries are available as NgModules (such as Material Design, Ionic, AngularFire2).`

Comment: there is no such package for native(https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/bebedfed24d6fbfa492e97f071e1d1b41e411280/packages), so what difference does it make, it was still the same for angular2 as well. Many people use angular2+ionic to generate mobile apps. Why are they claiming Native support as a feature addition in angular4 ?

Comment: @jb-nizel: I have used NativeScript/Ionic Framework. Maybe you should read the question properly. Ok let me repharase the question, does angular4 empower you to generate native mobile code/binary without any external framework which angular2 was not capable of ?

Comment: @jb-nizel: What you are mentioning is probably this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649500/turn-angular-js-2-app-into-mobile-app which were present in angular2 as well

Answer (score 1):

This is only a guess, but could it be that the third party code that provides the "native" platform was not yet available at the time of Angular 2 realease (it was only 6 mo ago, after all), but now new versions of ionic and the like have come out for use with Angular 2/4.

In other words perhaps the theory of that capability became reality since the last major release, and therefore warrants mention in new release notes and pr.